# Open Identity Server 4 Unauthorized UserInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, openid

I'm currently struggling with OpenIdentityServer 4 in ASP Core 1.1.
I'm able to grant tokens, using ResourceOwnerPassword grant type etc. Created my custom ResourcePasswordValidator etc.

Currently in my test application I retrieve a token with user credentials and all issues fine, however when I try to access the IdentityController with an [Authorize] attribute I'm redirected to unauthorized page and sent a 403 forbidden http code

I'm not sure what the issue is. I suspect it could be from scope/resource issue
Any help whatsoever appreciated.

Sample code for consumer

```
public class TestAuthentication
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public TestAuthentication()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
    }
    public async Task RunTest()
    {
        var token = await GetToken();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)) return;
        await GetClaims(token);

    }

    private async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var response = "";
        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");

        //var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "EduOne", "secret");
        //var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api");


        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret");
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice@mail.com", "Password1!", "api1");
       // var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice@mail.com", "Password1!", "openid");
        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Error:");
            Console.Out.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            Console.Out.Write(tokenResponse.ErrorDescription);

        }
        else
        {
            var extraClaims = new UserInfoClient(disco.UserInfoEndpoint);
            var identityClaims = await extraClaims.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            response = tokenResponse.Json.ToString();
            Console.Out.WriteLine($"token:    {response}");

        }
        return response;
    }
    private async Task GetClaims(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            var obj = JObject.Parse(token);
            var tok = obj["access_token"]?.ToString();
            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.SetBearerToken(tok);
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/identity");
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
            }
            else
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(JArray.Parse(content));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var m = e.Message;
            //throw;
        }

    }
    ~TestAuthentication()
    {

        _client = null;
    }
}
```

Code for setups:

Client =>

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ro.client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedScopes = {"api1" },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference
            },
```

User =>

```
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice@mail.com",
                Password = "Password1!",
                Claims =
                {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, "mail@mail.com")
                }
            },
```

Resource =>

```
              new IdentityResource("api1", new string[]{JwtClaimTypes.Email})
```

Startup =>

```
       app.UseIdentityServer();
        // app.UseIdentity();





        // app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ApiSecret = "secret",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            DiscoveryDocumentRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),

            ApiName = "FiserOpenIdentityApi",
            SupportedTokens = IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.SupportedTokens.Both,
            AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "api1", "FiserOpenIdentityApi" }
        });
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
        });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {

            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            ClientId = "ro.client",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            SaveTokens = false
        });
        //    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RESTApiV1",
                template: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

        });
        app.UseMongoDbForIdentityServer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hybrid flow. i think you are missing authenticationHeader in HttpClient.
Please follow below code, its working and it may help you.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
    var accessToken = await HttpContext
        .GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44323");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    var response = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
    {
        Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint,
        Token = accessToken
    });
    var address = response.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "address")?.Value;
    var add = new AddressViewModel();
    add.Address = address;
    return View(add);
```